# Can I establish a "one person company" in USA?

Tags: united-states, corporate-law, incorporation

Can I establish a one person company(with no co-founders) in USA? Will this company be restricted or face barriers to grow regards to law?

Comment: Are you a citizen?

Comment: @RonBeyer: No, but I like to know the laws. Can citizens do this?

Comment: Are you asking as a non-citizen wanting to start a business in the US? Or are you asking if US citizens can start companies? From the context of your question it seems you (a non-citizen) wants to start a company in the US...

Comment: @RonBeyer: Yes, I am a non-citizen who likes to start a company in the US. But my wife is a US citizen, then I can ask for citizenship if there is a huge difference in my way!

Comment: By "company" do you mean "business enterprise" or "corporation"?  You can start your own business, and you will be wholly responsible for what happens, or you can start a corporation, and have limited personal liability in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

Single owner limited liability companies and single owner corporations are permitted under U.S. law and provide full limited liability protection.

A single owner limited liability company is taxed either as a "disregarded entity" (a sole proprietorship if the owner is a natural person) or as a corporation, at the election of the owner.

A corporation with a single owner is taxed either as a "C corporation" or, as an S-corporation if it qualified to be one (the single owner must be a U.S. citizen natural person or one of a few special kinds of trusts).

A single owner business trust is also allowed (tax treatment can vary under different circumstances).

A sole proprietorship is the default choice and can operate under a trade name, but provides no limited liability protection, unlike other choices of entity.

If you reside in the U.S., but are not a citizen, your visa may or may not permit you to conduct various kinds of businesses through a company that you own. This depends on the nature of your visa, if any. A lawful permanent resident can conduct almost any kind of business although there may be some tax election choices that you can't make. Someone on a tourist visa, in contrast, is very greatly limited in what they could do with a company.